# Android 13: sending emails with Intent.ACTION_SEND doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

I use the following code to send emails from my app. It works perfectly well on Android versions below 13 ; but doesn't work on Android 13 (the email is created but the body of the email is empty)

My code :

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {email});

try {
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
trackException(ex);
}
```

Why do I get an email with empty body ? How to solve ?

Thanks.

**ANSWER :** use `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`

Comment: Same question what is solution for Intent.ACTION_SEND

Comment: Have you tried using `message/rfc822` as the type?

Comment: @Darshan Not solving the issue :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: We cannot see the type of body. Also try ACTION_SEND_TO.

Comment: Which email app receives your intent?

Comment: Found the solution. See the answer in my modified question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help others

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"<your email>"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, <your title>);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, <your body>);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).